# Creating multicolored meshed plots (connected scatter plots) using ListPlot

Tags: plotting, color

I would like to make colored scatter plots where the dots are connected by lines.  I have tried the following, using `Joined->True` to connect the dots and `Mesh->Full` to actually show the dots. I have tried using both `PlotStyle` and `MeshStyle` to color the lines and dots, respectively:

```
data1 = {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}};
data2 = {{0, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}};
data3 = {{0, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 5}};

ListPlot[{data1, data2, data3}, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
 Mesh -> Full, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}, MeshStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
```

which gives

[image: ListPlot]

Why are *all* of the dots blue? I would like their colors to match those of the lines (`data1` should be red, `data2` should be green, and `data3` should be blue). Is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `PlotMarkers` instead of `Mesh` and use an explicit graphics primitive for the marker.

```
ListLinePlot[{data1, data2, data3}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue},
    PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Rectangle[]}], 0.04}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why bother with `CurrentValue`? It works just fine without it, i.e use `Graphics[{Rectangle[]}]`, instead.

Comment: Using PlotMarkers also has the advantage that they work with legends (legends were not yet built in at the time when this post was written).